# C# Split into multiple arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, csv, split

I have a situation where I need to split 1 csv file by splitting the commas and storing the columns in the array

here is part of the csv file:

```
Go,noowner,nocolour,0,0,0,0,-200,0,0,0,0,0,0,1301,985
Vine Street,bank,brown,60,30,50,50,4,20,60,180,320,450,0,1190,985
Community Chest,noowner,nocolour,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1100,985
Coventry Street,bank,brown,60,30,50,50,2,10,30,90,160,250,0,1025,985
Income Tax,noowner,nocolour,0,0,0,0,200,0,0,0,0,0,0,935,985
```

Thanks in advance for the help
Alex

Comment: Can you share some more details? What kind of output do you want to get?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I was looking to store the first column (name) in an array, then in the other column (owner) in another array then the other column (colour) in the array. Hope this makes sense

Comment: @Alex.Duffield12: Why you want to store each column in a separate array which just contains one string? You can access each information in a single array via index, for example `fieldArray[0]` returns the name and `fieldArray[1]` the owner. (Edited [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67703345/284240) below accordingly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there's no header? Just select all lines and split them by comma:

```
string[][] allLinesFields = File.ReadLines(path)
    .Select(line => line.Split(','))
    .Where(array => array.Length == 16)
    .ToArray();
```

You can access all information via index, for example:

```
string nameOfFirstLine = allLinesFields[0][0];
string ownerOfFirstLine = allLinesFields[0][1];
string colorOfFirstLine = allLinesFields[0][2];
// and so on...
```

or use a loop to iterate all:

```
foreach(string[] fields in allLinesFields)
{
    string name = fields[0];
    string owner = fields[1];
    string color = fields[2];
}
```